# Are destructors called if the program is closed manually?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, destructor

I have a class, in one of its functions i use memset to allocate memory, then the program enters a loop, but my question is, even if i have set `delete[]` in the destructor, if i close the program by clicking the X will the destructor be called and the memory libreated? Or its leaking?

```
class Example {
public:
    int *a;
    Example() {
        a = new int[100];
        memset(a, 0, sizeof(a)); //Allocating memory
    }

    ~Example() {
        delete[] a;
    }
};

int main() {
    Example(); //Memory allocated.
    while (true) {
        //Other code here, if i close the program now (Pressing X), will the memory be liberated?
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "clicking X"?

Comment: @eerorika The top right button in a windows application, to close the programs. i.e. Chrome, I.E. Windows Explorer, etc.

Comment: That would be implementation, application  and OS dependent.

Comment: @eerorika sorry for not explaining it right, i'm talking about the `red X` that you can find on the top right corner of windows applications, dont know if that has a 'standart name'.

Comment: You mean the close button in the application window's *title bar*. (Or, equivalently, the Close menu item on the window's system menu.)

Comment: @GrazianoBolla You are creating a *console* app, not a *GUI* app.  If you close the *console window* itself, it will usually just terminate console apps that are running in it (console apps can install hooks to be notified of the console being closed, but that has to be opted into manually).

Comment: `Example();` creates an unused R value. So the destructor is called immediately at the end of the line before you enter the loop. Do you mean something like `auto v=Example();` or `Example v;`?

Comment: some destructor  will be called only if your code call it. all

Comment: [`ExitProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess) is called by the default console control handler. All other threads are terminated, and the entrypoints of DLLs are called for `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`, but C++ destructors will not be called.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: `sizeof(a)` is always 4 (or 8 in 64-bit programs...) You want to put `100` instead of `sizeof(a)`

Comment: The text of this question emphasizes leaking memory, while the title makes no mention of this. Which aspect are you more interested in -- if the destructor is called, or if memory is leaked after your program terminates? (The latter has a simpler, language-independent answer than the former.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention "the X" I assume you're talking about a Windows application. Linux is most likely similar but for other operating systems and ekbedded systems, your mileage may vary.

Now, about Windows. The short answer is - closing your application automatically releases all its memory. In fact, the OS is a lot more efficient about it than your app is, so if you know that your app is closing, you can skip all the destructors and memory releasing, etc. You'll save time. The OS will do it for you anyway. The same goes for closing any files, network sockets, kernel handles, windows, etc. The OS just summarily throws away everything belonging to your process in one fell swoop.

Comment: This is not the same as destructors being called.

Comment: @NeilButterworth True, but the OP was mostly concerned about memory leaking.

Answer (score 0):

> if i close the program by clicking the X will the destructor be called and the memory libreated?

No, that memory won't be deallocated automatically. There might be ways of putting hooks in your program that allows you to do some cleanup before the program is termintaed but it won't be in place by default.

> Or its leaking?j

When the program is terminated,  most run time systems make sure that the memory used by the program is made available for other programs. In that sense, the memory is not leaking but from the standpoint of the individual program, the memory is leaking.

**PS**

Please note that I am speaking from a mainstream desktop/laptop user's point of view. Embedded systems may behave completely differently.